# Postgres Sequence jumping by 32

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

We use sequences to maintain the number of orders at a particular business unit.
Last few we days, we have noticed that there have been has strange jumps ranging from 1 to 32 in the sequence numbers, multiple times a day.
The sequence which we have configured has a cache_value of 1.
Why is this happening and how can we resolve this?
I couldn't find much documentation regarding the same.

Comment: when you try to insert a value, session takes nexval from sequence. if transaction is rolled back, sequence number still is not rolled by one back. so if you `begin;nextval;rollback;` 32 times - no rows apper, but sequence get rolled forward

Comment: I got a similar error a few month ago, where the problem is query optimizer block ahead a few rows and then the sequence has some holes. Will try to check my history.

Comment: @VaoTsun, I am pretty sure that we won't have 32 consecutive rollbacks in our use case.  Had it been a small diffence ranging from 1 tp 5, I would agreed on what you are saying, but I don't think that is the case here.

Comment: dont hit me with feet if Im saying something very stupid - you could try creating trigger before insert, that will notify listening channel with details of insert. maybe it will help you catching not commited transactions and other actions

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL sequences can jump by 32 when you promote a secondary server to primary, and sometimes when PostgreSQL crashes hard and has to recover.

I have only seen it skip 32, and I haven't been able to change it by changing the sequence's cache value.

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1296642753.8673.29.camel%40gibralter, and the response https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20357.1296659633%40sss.pgh.pa.us, indicate that this is expected behavior in a crash condition.  I'm unsure if this only occurs if you're using Streaming Replication or not.

I thought it was a safety feature, in case the primary had committed records that had not been replicated to the secondary at the time of promotion.  Then a human would be able to manually dump and copy the records from the old-primary to the new-primary before wiping the old-primary.

This could indicate that your primary is crashing and recovering several times per day, which is not a good state to be in.

Comment: Hey @Craig,
Thanks for the reply, we use a single server, so I don't think this to be valid reason.
Haven't debugged it much, but I guess rollbacks/transaction failures, as mention by _vao are the reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL uses a technique called "preallocation" to improve the performance of sequences. When a sequence is preallocated, the server reserves a block of sequence values in memory, rather than generating each value individually. By default, PostgreSQL preallocates 32 sequence values at a time.

This preallocation technique reduces the number of times PostgreSQL needs to access the disk to get the next sequence value, which can significantly improve performance in high-concurrency environments where many clients are generating sequence values simultaneously.

While this behavior may seem strange or unexpected, it is actually a feature of PostgreSQL that is designed to improve performance. If you need to change the preallocation value, you can do so by altering the sequence with the INCREMENT BY clause. For example, to change the preallocation to 10, you could run the following SQL command:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_sequence INCREMENT BY 10;
```